# Default generics type derivation in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Why does "value.type" throw an error "Property 'type' does not exist on type 'P'"

```js
class A<T extends {}, P = { type: keyof T, value: T[keyof T] }> {
  constructor (value: P) {
    if (value.type) {

    }
  }
}
```

Using extends is OK：

```js
class A<T extends {}, P extends { type: keyof T, value: T[keyof T] }> {
  constructor (value: P) {
    if (value.type) {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic type parameter [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) (case 1) is different from a generic [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) (case 2).

#### Case 1: type parameter default

```
class A<P = { type: string, value: unknown }> {
  constructor(value: P) {
    if (value.type) { } // error, 'type' does not exist on type 'P' (good!)
  }
}

new A({ foo: "bar" })  // P is { foo: string; }, cannot rely on 'type' to be present.
```

You cannot rely on `P` to have a `type` property here. A default is only chosen, if the type parameter is not set by the caller (cannot be inferred and is not set manually). But that depends on the caller side.

#### Case 2: generic constraint

```
class AExtends<P extends { type: string, value: unknown }> {
  constructor(value: P) {
    if (value.type) { } // works
  }
}

new AExtends({ value: "bar" }) // error, 'type' is missing
new AExtends({ type: "foo", value: "bar" }) // works
```

The compiler can be sure, that `value: P` always has a property `type`. It is enforced by the constraint `extends { type: keyof T, value: T[keyof T] }`.

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=70&pln=3&pc=71#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AFaBeaBvaAXAngBwFMAuaCLAJwEsA7AcwBpoA3MEAV2OjeoGtqB7AO7VoAXwB8GAFDRowftTLk2wLP3IAKFu06IAlNNmzKAM2hbWHAHS5CBzKOgB6J9ALly6xgHJbBb9AAJvwEMAJYbgAelGTQCtj4BNDeiAEatPz8gQCEejJiUqJSUtQEgnAamCaZJABEAEZg5LViBs6uyDEY0NX8JEo0tADcBVKgkDCwAKKRWATUgRBIUXMLMJh+-RSDjNocJNx8QiIShnIKSipqmnu69vnGZhY6Non2Yu3Qguo8EPlFRRKZTgM1Wi0qzEsnAaTRaogMLjcHi8yT8AS6AFsYhBBkDytNZvNwRtEnVerVdlC6o1mq1Pt9yL8gA) (simplified your code a bit; e.g. `T` is not needed)